# Why will points in the Epilog "get lost" when combining two plots using Show?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I need to mark four points in a single graph, math does it separately, but when I put together both graphs, two points of a line disappear, I really do not know why.

```
(* first graph *)

w1 = ListLinePlot[ {{0, 88}, {24.2, 0}},
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Large,Point[{{0, 88}, {24.2, 0}}]},
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> Black, 
    GridLines -> Automatic
]

(* second graph *)

w2 = ListLinePlot[ {{0, 25.3}, {88, 0}},
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Large,Point[{{0, 25.3}, {88, 0}}]},
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> Black, 
    GridLines -> Automatic
]

(* combined graphs *)

Show[w1, w2, PlotRange -> All]
```

Any suggestion? plz :)

Comment: The `Show` inherits the `Epilog` from the first plot (`w1`). Move the `Epilog` to the `Show`: 

`Show[w1, w2, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Large, 
   Point[{{0, 88}, {24.2, 0}, {0, 25.3}, {88, 0}}]}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have voted to reopen this question. While I totally agree with you, that for the *general case* of options and prologs/epilogs there are answers - this question is specifically asking for "points" in the epilog being lost. That use-case has  a solution (cf. my answer) not yet demonstrated in the general answers you linked.

Comment: @gwr `Show[combineShow[w1, w2], PlotRange -> All]` seems to do the job, no?: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BBvpw.png -- Mr.Wizard wrote `combineShow` specifically to address the problem of combining the `Epilog` and `Prolog` settings of graphics (but made it more general than that).

Comment: @MichaelE2 It certainly is addressing the problem (I never doubted that), but my point was and is:  This is a very special case (points in the epilog) which does not need the whole shebang of Mr. Wizard's general solution. Using `Mesh` and `Meshstyle` works without all of that.

Comment: @gwr Perhaps if the OP agreed to edit the question to focus on how to show data points along with graph, there would be support for reopening it. As it stands, I think the questions should be linked. Neither the Q or your answer is going away. Your answer is about a specific aspect of the general issue of `Epilog` that the OP seems interested in. My way for dealing with this has been to skip `Epilog` and put it all in `Graphics`, which seems both simple and obvious: `Show[w1, w2, Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large,  Point[{{0, 88}, {24.2, 0}, {0, 25.3}, {88, 0}}]}]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bob Hanlon has explained, `Show` will only inherit the options from the first element. You may consider working with [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html):

```
SetOptions[ ListLinePlot, Frame -> True, FrameTicksStyle -> Black, GridLines -> Automatic, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red];

w1 = ListLinePlot @ { {0, 88}, {24.2, 0} };
w2 = ListLinePlot @ { {0, 25.3}, {88, 0} };
Show[ w1, w2, PlotRange -> All ]
```

[image: Show]